# TYPO3 Extbase class to handle general mysql queries

Tags: typo3, extbase

I'm looking for the best practice to do a mysql dump of a 8 tables in my Extbase CommandController.
Since an Extbase Repository handles only one specific table, it seems to be the wrong location to execute general mysql queries.

In which class should I put a raw mysql statement that affects multiple tables?

Comment: How about an ExportController that isn't bound to an entity at all, and AbstractRepositories that implement a dump method, that the ExportController can call? Other than that, I think I'd implement an extension of TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Query rather than TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository

Comment: @cephei_vv What is the purpose of your Extbase application? Extbase follows the principles of domain-driven design and separation of concerns.
I it's about creating a "mysql dump" then probably use the OS tool `mysqldump` directly - if it's about "listing an arbitrary amount of database tables in a user interface" it's a different story.

Comment: @oliver-hader My CommandController makes a backup of a few tables before importing new data from an API. 
That's what I did, I made a BackupService and used `exec()` to run `mysqldump`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue is solved.

I made a BackupService class and run a `mysqldump` command with `exec()`.